# Multiplying the mean row values by row-specific multipliers after filtering out min and max values

Tags: python, pandas, mean

```
data = {'players': ('Aaron', 'Jane', 'Tim', 'Sam', 'Max', 'Bob', 'John', 'Rick', 'Dick'),
     'score1': (97, 94, 96, 91, 102, 89, 97, 93, 82),
     'score2': (98, 89, 88, 86, 89, 93, 79, 92, 101),
     'score3': (84, 90, 93, 99, 100, 103, 91, 92, 92),
     'score4': (95, 92, 90, 98, 97, 85, 93, 93, 86),
     'score5': (84, 90, 98, 92, 99, 94, 92, 90, 96),
     'multiplier': (3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4)}
```

How can I remove the min and max scores of each player, take the mean of the remaining 3 scores and then multiply that mean by the multiplier of each player to be displayed in an additional column as a dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to add your expected output, your effort towards solving the problem, and where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that in the future. This was probably too much for me and I didn't even know where to start! Should have done some thing a bit simpler first

Answer (score 0):

you oculd do:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
scores = data.loc[:, "score1": 'score5'].copy().astype(float)
maxes = np.argmax(scores.values, axis=1)
scores.values[range(len(scores)), maxes] = np.nan
mins = np.argmin(scores.values, axis=1)
scores.values[range(len(scores)), mins] = np.nan
data['your_name'] = scores.mean(axis=1) * data.multiplier
```